# Angularjs $http service returns uncomplete data

Tags: angularjs, store

I have a service to load and set store data:

```
        return $http({
              method  : 'GET',
              url     : 'store.json',
              headers : {
                  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
              }
        })
        .success(function(data) 
        {

            console.log("MaterialtypeService - SET DATA", data);

            if ("object" == typeof data) {
                store.setItems(data);
            } 
            else {
                // @todo
            }

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
            {
                $scope.messages = 'There was a network error. Try again later.';
                console.error(data);
        })
        ;
```

If I call the store-url manualy the response is:

```
[
    {"id":"1","label":"S355J2+N"},
    {"id":"2","label":"S355J2+K"}
]
```

But the data in success function looks like this:

```
[
    {$$hashKey:"object24", id:undefined, label:"S355J2+N"},
    {$$hashKey:"object25", id:undefined, label:"S355J2+K"}
]
```

What happens with the content of "id"??

In my other stores it works fine...

regards
Bytecounter

Comment: Can you show response of the server?

Comment: Look at "If I call the store-url manualy the response is" for response data

Comment: I found the error....I wrote in a ng-selected expression "=" instead of "=="...

Comment: I didn't asked response for manually call, I asked for response, when script doing this call. About `==`. Thats why you have to provide more code.